# Writing data in json file array throw node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to write data in my posts.json file throw index.js node.js file and that id automatically is given to post.

This is index.js file:

```
const { ALL } = require('dns');
const { text } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('To see all posts add to url /api/posts.')

});
app.get('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('posts.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
  console.error(err);
  }else{
  res.json(JSON.parse(data))};
});
});

app.get('/api/posts/:id', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('posts.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
  console.error(err);
  }else{
    const resArray = JSON.parse(data)
    const posts = resArray.find(posts => posts.id == req.params.id)
    res.send(posts)
}});
});

app.post('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
  fs.writeFile('posts.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
  console.error(err);
  }else{

// here should go the code

}});
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started'); 
});
```

I tried lots of variants, but none of them worked.
Here is posts.json file part:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
      "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "qui est esse",
      "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
    },
...
]
```

I need a field in a tab where to input the title and body under all posts.

Comment: The second argument for the `writeFile` should be the data that you want to write, and the third argument is options. [see Node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to write a JSON data first you will need to read the JSON structure to modify it like so:

```js
app.post('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('posts.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        const resArray = JSON.parse(data)
        resArray.push(data)
        fs.writeFile('posts.json', JSON.stringify(resArray));
    }});
});
```

You can calculate your id easily from resArray when adding a new post for example you can find the max previous id and add one to it like so:

```js
data.id = Math.max(...resArray.map(item => item.id)) + 1
```